# How to authenticate in UIWebView using RestKit and WSSE?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uikit, restkit, wsse

I'm wondering if it is possible to access html page via UIWebView using X-WSSE authentication and RestKit? What I was thinking about is just getting HTTP response as NSData and then show it in web view, but I'm looking for a more appropriate approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how RestKit will help if your download content is HTML. `UIWebView` has a `loadRequest:` method so you should just create an `NSURLRequest` and set the auth headers then pass it straight to the web view.